# How to close other tabs in IntelliJ using keyboard shortcut?

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any default keyboard shortcut to close all tabs except the active one? It can be done by right-clicking the tab and choosing `Close Others` but I'd like to do this using only my keyboard.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> and write `Close Others`. Select the one with `Editor Close Actions`.

Or assign it your own shortcut.
Open `Settings` > `Keymap`. Search for `Close others` (or find it under `Main menu` > `Window` > `Editor tabs`.

Comment: I followed this and added the keymap for `cmd shift w`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to access the tab context menu using the keyboard.

There's an [open issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6219) against IntelliJ for this.

Their suggestion is to add that action (tab > close others) to a [quick list](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/configuring-quick-lists.html) and you can then invoke the quick list action via a keyboard shortcut.